# Different results in same logistic regression model from sklearn and same dataset

Tags: logistic-regression

I got this strange behavior when deploying my logistic regression trained in scikit-learn into production. I trained the model on my own machine and stored it in form of `.pickle`. I use the same set of data for both locally and on server side (with docker) generating four columns for each sample in this binary classification problem: `probability_of_class_0`, `probability_of_class_1`, `y_true, y_predict`; where `y_true` and `y_hat` refer to the true label and the predicted label respectively for that sample row/record. And the `probability_of_class_0`, `probability_of_class_1` means the predicted probability of a sample belonging to class 0 or 1 respectively.

Let `_o` denote the results I get locally and `_s` be those from the exact same model on the server. I checked that despite the fact that `y_hat_o` and `y_hat_s` are exactly the same, the `probability_of_class_0_s`, `probability_of_class_1_s` are different than `probability_of_class_0_o`, `probability_of_class_1_o`.

I was not aware there are any stochastic elements in my model building (i.e. in the logistic regression model itself, according to the documentation). But I am not sure if that is because there are just two different versions of scikit-learn on 2 machine. But what worries me more is that regardless of the versions, the results should always be the same. Or more dreading is that, there are other problems that I am not aware that contribute to this problem?

Comment: A few places to check: 1. print and compare the model parameters on local and on server; 2. check if there is any processing pipeline deployed differently on local vs. server; 3. print the input data *immediately before feeding into the model* and verify they are identical.